# How to take the n-th element of a "collection"-resulting formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Recently, some new functions are added to Excel, resulting in a collection of cells, like `Sequence()` or `Filter()`.

Does anybody know how to take an element of such a result?

E.g. I would like to know the fifth element of an arithmetic progression, starting with 8 and having a step of 12. I can simply do:

```
=SEQUENCE(5,1, 8, 12)
```

... and then go to the last cell of that sequence, but I would like to do something like:

```
=SEQUENCE(5,1, 8, 12) [5]
```

... but this, obviously, does not work.

Comment: `SEQUENCE(5,8,1,12)` does not begin with 8; it begins with 1. And why are you creating a 2D-version of this sequence, which seems to make interrogating it less straightforward? Why not simply `SEQUENCE(40,,1,12)`, which can then be indexed easily?

Comment: If a 2D starting array is unavoidable, you could simply use `TOCOL` to convert it into a 1D array, e.g. `=TOCOL(SEQUENCE(5,8,1,12))`.

Comment: @JosWoolley: Thanks for the remark, it was a typo and I've corrected my question. As for the indexing, how do you do that? (I'm not looking for 2D-arrays, I just want to take the fifth element of a 1D-array)

Comment: If the SEQUENCE only returns one column you can use `INDEX(SEQUENCE(5,1, 8, 12),5)`

Comment: @Ike: your function is correct, but not your remark: this works also on a 2D-array, as you can see: `=INDEX(SEQUENCE(5,5,8,12),2,3)`. Please put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Maybe something like `=INDEX(TOCOL(<YourArray>,3),5)`. This would work with any 1d or 2d array, stack it by row into a 1d array but exclude all empty cells and errors and then return the 5th element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=INDEX(SEQUENCE(5,1, 8, 12), 5)` will return the element of the 5th row and first column.

If there is only one column, like in your sample-sequence - it is the 5th element.

If you have more columns, you would have to decide what to put in the column part of the `Index`-formula. As an example, this will first create a 5x5 matrix with the arithmetic progression, starting at 8 with step 12, and then take the second row, third column:

```
=INDEX(SEQUENCE(5,5,8,12),2,3)
```

Result : 92.